# Away 3D Face Link

Tags: actionscript, away3d

I'm recently playing with Away3D Library and have a problem in finding Face center in Away3D. Why Away3DLite has a face.center feature while Away3D doesn't have it ? and what is the alternative solution for this ?

Comment: I don't see center in Away3d Lite either. Which version of the library are you using? - I'm looking at away3D lite 1.0.2
http://away3d.com/livedocs/lite_1.0.2_lib/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the center of a face, it's simply the average position of all the vertices making up that face:

```
function getFaceCenter(f : Face) : Vector3D
{
    var vert : Vertex;
    var ret : Vector3D = new Vector3D;

    for each (vert in f.vertices) {
        ret.x += vert.x;
        ret.y += vert.y;
        ret.z += vert.z;
    }

    ret.x /= f.vertices.length;
    ret.y /= f.vertices.length;
    ret.z /= f.vertices.length;

    return ret;
}
```

The above is a very simple function to calculate an average, although on a 3D vector instead of a simple scalar number. That average is the center of all the vertices in the face.

If you need to do this a lot, optimize the method by preventing it from allocating a vector (by passing in a vector to which the return values should be written) and create a temporary variable for the vertex list length instead of dereferencing it through two object references like min (`f` and `vertices`), which is unnecessarily heavy.